# How to add header left on Tab.Screen using "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabs, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` Package but I don't understand how to add a header left on `Tab.Screen` tag?

And also can I add an image on the header left?

Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from "./TabScreen/Home";
import Category from "./TabScreen/Category";
import Search from "./TabScreen/Search";
import Profile from "./TabScreen/Profile";
import Colors from "../../../Style_Sheet/Colors";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs =()=>{
    return(
      <Tab.Navigator tabBarPosition="bottom" screenOptions={{
          tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: Colors.dark,
          },
      }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerTitle:"Explore",headerTintColor:Colors.white,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.dark}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Category" component={Category} options={{headerTitle:"",headerTintColor:Colors.white,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.dark},headerLeft:{}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} options={{headerTitle:"Explore",headerTintColor:Colors.white,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.dark}}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{headerTitle:"Explore",headerTintColor:Colors.white,headerStyle:{backgroundColor:Colors.dark}}}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
export default Tabs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

Here is the code where you can add the headerLeft on Tabs.Screen tag.

```
<Tabs.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
          title="Info"
          color="#fff"
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
```

and also you can add image or Button under the headerLeft Tag, for more details follow this [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/)

Comment: How to pass 'button press' event to rendered component?

Comment: If you need to render this component. You need to update any state. But if you want to navigate to the other screen you just add navigation on that onPress event.